# Github post commit or merge amend/create file

Tags: git, github

I would like to ask the best way to add a file to github master branch every time there is a commit or merge to master.

The file should be named something like build.c and in the file should be the master branch commit count after the commit or merge.  I would like this to be done from the remote repository so git hooks wont work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't automate github other than hooks. Also, I would be *very* afraid about this. You push to master, the code detects this, adds a commit, it pushes to master. Github will detect this, call your hook, you add a commit, you push to master, github calls your hook, you add a commit, you push to master, github calls your hook. You see where this is going?

Comment: This isn't possible without hooks

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible with github, and would be a really bad idea.

"Adding a file to github master branch" means adding a commit. So you would be adding an extra commit to master branch every time you pushed. You wouldn't be able to commit again without pulling or force pushing. This file would change with each commit, so almost any merge would be a conflict.

What you should do is modify your build process to calculate the number you want and put that in a file that doesn't get committed. See also git-describe which gives each commit a unique identity that is more human readable than just the Git SHA.

Comment: Yes, this looks like an XY problem. And the imagined solution is indeed bad.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to record is merely the commit count, I'd suggest [git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes).

Notes are attached to commits, which avoids rewriting the commit or directly creating new commits to the branch.

To add a note to the head of `master`,

```
# in the local repository
git fetch origin master
# add a note
git notes add -m "commit count:$(git rev-list FETCH_HEAD --count)" FETCH_HEAD
# push the note to the remote repository
git push origin refs/notes/commits
```

To show the notes,

```
git log --notes
```

To hide the notes,

```
git log --no-notes
```

To retrive only the note of a commit,

```
git log -1 $commit --pretty=%N
```

Comment: guess there is no option to do this from the remote side only local guess git hooks is the way to go.

Comment: @malik I suspect the best way to go is to tell us why you need a file called build.c in the repository and what the file is for. Give us a bigger picture, and we will try to help you find a bigger solution.

Comment: Well @rjmunro I am working on a git repository and we can not directly commit to master we have to make a branch and issue a pull request that is authorised by the head developer.  The application was made in SDL2 and it has been getting releases manually with the build number being the head commit count.  The problem is the application is missing the build number so I need some way to add it into the application.  I was thinking to add a file with the current head commit count like build.h that can be read by the application.

Answer (score 0):

This pre-commit hook will do for now.

```
#!/bin/sh
#pre-hook to log master commit count then add branch ahead of master and record into a build_number.h file.
countM=$(git rev-list master --count) #master commit count
countB=$(($(git rev-list master.. --count) + 2)) #branch ahead of master commit count +1 for the merge +1 for this commit.
echo $(($countM + $countB)) > build_number.h
git add build_number.h
exit 0
```